# New internal testing app versions are not available for testers even though it says they are

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-testing, google-play-internal-testing

I have a very strange issue that I have been stuck on all day.

My CI/CD automatically uploads the latest version from the main branch to the internal testing track in Google Play Console a few times a day.

As you can see in the image below, the latest version in the internal testing track is a few hours old, and it says it’s “available to internal testers”.

[image: internal testing latest release available for internal testers]

However, I’ve noticed that testers actually don’t get updated versions, and when I open the testers invite link and check the internal testing app out in Google Play in the browser it says **Updated on Aug 8, 2022**.

[image: Updated on Aug 8]

This matches what's in the Release History in the Google Play Console.

[image]

Additionally, when I install the app on my device through internal testing it says **21.07.2022**.

[image: Udated on July 21]

### What I've tried / thought could be the problem

Around August 8 I activated Managed Publishing, so I thought that could've been the issue, but [according to the docs](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859654?hl=en#zippy=%2Chow-does-managed-publishing-work-with-internal-testing-will-the-update-be-covered-by-managed-publishing) Managed Publishing should not affect internal testing at all. The app is not yet released on production but on August 8 I did promote a version to production and it passed the review, but since I have managed publishing turned on it is not yet available for users.

I've read tons of similar issues on SO and in other places, but I haven't found any solution to my problem. I’m not sure what could be wrong. I’ve had the usual struggles with internal testing versions being slow to be delivered to testers, having to clear cache etc, but this is something completely new to me.

### Update

When going to the start page of the Google Play Console and pressing on All Apps the information for the app says the following:

**App status:** Closed Testing
**Update status:** Ready to publish

[image]

Perhaps this is a hint to what is wrong? Maybe it is related to the closed testing track not being published due to Managed Publishing?

### My question

**Why is the latest internal testing version in Google Play Console not available for testers?**

I am super grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted google and got the following response:

> As per checking, the testers are listed on internal and closed testing tracks. Each track must be unique for if the testers are present on both tracks, issues may occur. I recommend to remove or uncheck the testers lists from closed testing track. Once done, testers must opt-out from the testing first, then clear their cache and opt-in to the testing.

> Another option is to deactivate either one of the testing tracks, then testers must opt-out, clear cache and opt-in again to the testing.

This didn't work, however, since any changes to the testers list for Closed Testing was blocked by managed publishing.

What I ended up doing was to turn off managed publishing and instantly unpublishing the app, as I don't want it available for users yet. Now it's unpublished for all the tracks and I have created a new "beta" app to be able to use its internal testing track. I'm very disappointed with Managed Publishing and will think twice before ever using it again.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem.  I uploaded to "Internal testing" and was not able to install on my own devices.  I then pushed the App to "Closed testing" (same app, same testers) and I was then able to install the App.  It still gives a warning that the App has not been reviewed, but it enables installs on tester devices from my email list.[Closed testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ir41y.jpg)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32842686)